# data model for Customer-> Account -> Service

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am new to data modelling. I have a requirement like below
There are 3 dimensions by name Customer, Account and Service. Here One Customer can have multiple accounts, each account can have multiple services. This is for telecom domain.

I have designed a bridge table with Custmer key,Account Key and Service Key, start date and end date.

Can someone suggest on the approach to model the above case. 
Also ETL approach to populate the bridge table.

Awaiting for response.

Thanks in advance
- Siddesh

Comment: Are you definitely decided to use star-schema? With such design it could be easier to build snow-flake instead of star-schema. Which ETL tool you're going to use?

Comment: Hi Stevan, Thanks for the reply. Thought of snowflake as well, here the problem is this hierarchy varies from operator to operator in telecom. If we make snowflake, we will have to change the design for each operator. If it is bridge, changes would be minimal. I am using Talend ETL tool. Facing difficulties to populate the bridge table using talend.

Comment: If there are different sources, your sql's will be different either in staging area. In that case, you've started right. Dimension table, with Surrogate Primary Key, Customer Key, Accout Key and Service Key. Add all properties for each level in hierarchy (Customer Info, Account Info, Service Info). You can even add level 'Telecom Operator' as top level in hierarchy. That's how you will separate services logicaly (by Operator) and pshisicaly (by source). I'm talking about general case, I don't have your source db schemas. Share it with us for further help.